# Is there a way to disable debugmode in wxMaxima?

Tags: wxmaxima

I am not able to change debugmode to false in wxMaxima.

I tried using the manual and documentation from wxMaxima but I still wasn't able. I even tried this code:

```
%i1 debugmode(true);
%o1 **true**

%i2 debugmode(false);
%o2 *No print*
```